# Find all $p$ such that $p, 2p+1, 4p^2+1$ are prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p, 2p+1, 4p^2+1$ are primes, find $p$.

I found $2,3$ and $5$. But, are there are others solutions?

Comment: I am sorry, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that all prime numbers can be written in the form $6k\pm 1$ i.e. $p \equiv 1, 5 \mod 6$ - except for $2, 3$.

By checking, $p = 2, 3$ satisfy the required properties. Assume $p \geq 5$.

$2p+1 \equiv 1, 5 \mod 6$

$2p \equiv 0, 4 \mod 6$

$p \equiv 0, 3, 2, 5 \mod 6$

Since $p$ is also a prime, $p \equiv 5 \mod 6 \implies p=6k+5$

So we can just search for numbers in the form $6k+5$. Simple hand calculation ([jk](https://tio.run/##XY2xDsIwDETn9iuOASkpBTUFFiS@BUVqCpZaNwphyNcHNwMgPNnvznc@xcfCx71PPuU8uBH0vPlAs1OsL3UVXHwFBmNzhYHlAXaaFGMLWlGHcQmyEiNYvjvVt5iJFXEUU9OgO5w1djAtWGtd16s9fu3CTSdj1i76KY@6lH3uHo38SdAfPxUuRX0RJaUSgSMkIec3)) gives $p = 2, 3, 5, 233, 653, 683, 1013, 1973, 2003, \cdots$

Answer (score 0):

The [generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) implies that there are infinitely many such $p$.

Comment: Sequence is now in OEIS as [A333803](https://oeis.org/A333803)